# Sphinx - Need to work out which index each search result is coming from (has 4 indexes)

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I have used the following Sphinx example on my website, it works ok however as I have indexed multiple tables - I need to be able to work out which table each search result is coming from and generate a URL accordingly.
http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/example5.php?q=test (note this isn't my site)

My code (minus the MySQL connection details on pastebin)
http://pastebin.com/brbUu5VD

eg..
if it is a news article... something like this..

```
mysite.com/news/view/123/my-page-title
```

if is an library article then it would alter slightly

```
mysite.com/library/view/99/article-title
```

Can anyone suggest how this would be done - thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to add a new attribute to your indexes.

Eg

```
index 1
sql_query = SELECT id, 1 as table_id, .... 
sql_attr_uint = table_id

index 2
sql_query = SELECT id, 2 as table_id, .... 
sql_attr_uint = table_id
```

you get that attribute back in search results, which you can then use to create the link.

Comment: Wow.. how strange I just found your website with all the sphinx materials - thanks for that tip! :)

Comment: Hi Barry - would this look right to you? I get error when I try to re-index it all (unknown key name 'sql_attr_unit')

http://pastebin.com/vuU7sA4R

Comment: No it does not. sql_attr_uint goes in the 'source' section. And it defines a column from the 'sql_query' that should be stored.